# Netlogo: agentset of patches to single agent

Tags: netlogo

I have a list of turtles (carriers) that i'm trying to narrow down in my go method.

Here is my program:

```
globals [
metal-sheets
cut-sheets
standard-skeleton
finished-standard-skeleton
prestige-skeleton
finished-prestige-skeleton
]

breed[carriers carrier]

turtles-own [
on-job?
]

patches-own [
processing-time
  machine-type ;;cutter, standard-welder, prestige-welder, riveter
  status ;;import, export, pending
]

to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape carriers "circle"
  create-carriers number-of-carriers ;;number-of-carriers is a slider
  [set color grey
  set on-job? false
  setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
  setup-patches
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-patches
  ask patches [
    if pxcor = 1 and pycor = 1 [set machine-type "cutter"]
    if pxcor = 1 and pycor = 5 [set machine-type "standard-welder"]
    if pxcor = 5 and pycor = 1 [set machine-type "prestige-welder"]
    if pxcor = 5 and pycor = 5 [set machine-type "riveter"]

    if machine-type = "cutter" 
    [set pcolor red
    set status "import"]
    if machine-type = "standard-welder" 
    [set pcolor green
    set status "import"]
    if machine-type = "prestige-welder" 
    [set pcolor blue
    set status "import"]
    if machine-type = "riveter" 
    [set pcolor yellow
    set status "import"]
  ]
end

to Go

  let cutter patches  with [machine-type = "cutter"]
    let standard-welder patches with [machine-type = "standard-welder"]
    let prestige-welder patches with [machine-type = "prestige-welder"]
    let riveter patches with [machine-type = "riveter"]

  let free-carriers carriers with [on-job? = false]
  let closest-carrier min-one-of free-carriers [distance cutter] ;;Distance expects agent, got agentset

  ask closest-carrier [
    set color green
  ]
end
```

I'm getting an error on the line `let closest-carrier min-one-of free-carriers [distance cutter]` saying that distance expected a agent but got a agentset although there only is one agent in the set.

The full error message is:
`DISTANCE expected input to be an agent but got the agentset (agentset, 1 patch) instead.`

How do narrow down the patches to one patch?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if there happens to be only one agent in the agentset, it is still an agentset. Put a `one-of` in front, which selects one agent from the agentset and therefore changes the way the code interprets the code